# Huawei E303 internet key with Linux CentOS?

Tags: networking, centos

Are there any programmes, downloads, patches, drivers available to use a Huawei E303 Internet Key in CentOS?

Comment: Are you actually having a problem with it?

Comment: First run `xev` and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

`usb_modeswitch` and `usb_modeswitch-data` packages may be quite useful. I have found (through rpmfind.net) them to be available at DAG repository: http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=usb_modeswitch&submit=Search+...

Answer (score 0):

Some Ubuntu sites claim that it ships with configuration for Linux (even though it doesn't say so on the packaging). It seems to be Ubuntu-specific, and only for i686. No details given in my cursory checks.

Out of curiosity, I tried a Huawei 3G stick (sorry, unknown version) on Fedora 17 a while back, and it worked out of the box.